# "error: implicit declaration of function 'srand' is invalid in C99" Adding stdlib.h header removes this error but why?

Tags: c

Initially, I didn't have the stdlib.h header on the file and I got the error on VS Code but the code seemed correct to me, and I resolved any other existing errors, so I copied and pasted the code onto an online compiler (without adding the stdlib.h header) and the code worked perfectly. Is this because I may just have an older or maybe bad toolset installed onto my computer for VS Code? I have the program written below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

main()
{
    int dice1, dice2;
    int total1, total2;
    time_t t;
    char ans;

    //Remember that this is needed to to make sure each random number
    //generated is different

    srand(time(&t));

    //This would give you a number between 0 and 5, so the + 1
    //makes it 1 to 6

    dice1 = (rand() % 5) + 1;
    dice2 = (rand() % 5) + 1;
    total1 = dice1 + dice2;
    printf("First roll of the dice was %d and %d, ", dice1, dice2);
    printf("for a total of %d.\n\n\n", total1);

    //Asks you to make a guess for your next roll.

    do 
    {
        puts("Do you think the next roll will be ");
        puts("(H)igher, (L)ower, or (S)ame?\n");
        puts("Enter H, L, or S to reflect your guess.");

        scanf(" %c", &ans);
        ans = toupper(ans);
    }

    while ((ans != 'H') && (ans != 'L') && (ans != 'S'));

    //Roll the dice a second time to get your second total

    dice1 = (rand() % 5) + 1;
    dice2 = (rand() % 5) + 1;
    total2 = dice1 + dice2;

    //Display the second total for the user 

    printf("\nThe second roll was %d and %d, ", dice1, dice2);
    printf("for a total of %d.\n\n\n", total2);

    //Now compare the two dice totals against the users guess
    //and tell them if they were right or not

    if (ans == 'L')
    {
        if (total2 < total1)
        {
            printf("Good job! You were right!\n");
            printf("%d is lower than %d\n", total2, total1);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Sorry! %d is not lower than %d\n\n", total2, total1);
        }
    }

    else if (ans == 'H')
    {
        if (total2 > total1)
        {
            printf("Good job! You were right!\n");
            printf("%d is higher than %d\n", total2, total1);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Sorry! %d is not lower than %d\n\n", total2, total1);
        }
    }

    else if (ans == 'S')
    {
        if (total2 == total1)
        {
            printf("Good job! You were right!\n");
            printf("%d is the same as %d\n", total2, total1);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Sorry! %d is not lower than %d\n\n", total2, total1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Different standard library implementations may incidentally include other headers, but you should not rely on that behavior.  For example, perhaps the online compiler's version of `stdio.h` has a `#include <stdlib.h>`, and your local `stdio.h` does not.  You should always include the headers that you need.

Comment: C90 supported implicit function declaration, but it would be implicitly declared as `extern int srand();`, which is not compatible with the actual `srand` function. Implicit function declaration was removed from C11 for safety reasons (but some compilers still support it, hopefully with a warning).

Comment: @IanAbbott — implicit function declaration was removed from C99, twelve years or so before C11.   Compilers working in a standard-compliant mode must produce a warning about undeclared functions.  However, the declaration does not have to include a prototype — that is a more stringent requirement which is still not enforced by the C standard, AFAIK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, sorry I skipped a version by mistake. It is not the lack of prototype that makes the implicit declaration of `srand` incompatible with the actual function; it is the difference in return type.

Comment: OT: regarding: `main()`  there are only two valid signatures for `main()` they are:  `int main( void)` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Answer (score 4):

A declaration must be provided.<sup>[1]</sup> `#include <stdlib.h>` is the [normal way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) of doing that.

> Defined in header `<stdlib.h>`
> `void srand( unsigned seed );`

Maybe the online compiler implicitly includes it for you, or maybe it was indirectly included by another library. Regardless, you should use `#include <stdlib.h>`.

---

1. In C99 or later, this is the case for all functions. (Do note that a definition acts as a declaration.) Before C99, `srand` still needed one because its signature didn't match the default one.

Comment: Just to reinforce it: never count on indirect includes.

Comment: @Chris, It's not indirect includes that's the problem; it's undocumented indirect includes.  You could, for example, include `foo.h` which is documented to include `foo_bar.h`, `foo_baz.h` and more, and that would be fine. But you shouldn't count on `stdio.h` including `stdlib.h` even if it currently does so in a specific environment.

Comment: Even then, if I'm using something directly defined in `foo_bar.h` I'd be tempted to include it alongside `foo.h`. Keeps me from creating problems if I decide I don't need `foo.h` and decide to delete or comment out that include.

Comment: @Chris You say that, except you use `#include <stdlib>` even if the the function is actually declared in a file included by stdlib, as is the case on some platforms.

Comment: I don't see `#include <stdlib.h>` as something I'm likely to comment out or delete.

Comment: @Chris, I think you misread what I said? I'm saying that even if `srand`'s declaration isn't actually in stdlib, you'd still use only stdlib, contradicting what you said two comments ago. Indirect inclusion is common and perfectly fine, as long as you include the header the documentation says you should include.